# Screencapture:get Bitmap from Textureview and display in imageview android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-textureview

can anyone suggest me how to get Bitmap from Textureview and display in Imageview

I used following link but it didn't help.
[Advice on Android TextureView and Bitmap Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705322/advice-on-android-textureview-and-bitmap-rendering)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap = yourTextureView.getBitmap();
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```